# Me gustaría separar texto espaciado en una tabla html al pegarlo en su primera casilla

Tags: javascript, html, html-tabla

me preguntaba si hay una forma de tomar un texto con espacios y pegarlo en la primera casilla de una tabla html editable que sea capaz de separarlo en distintas celdas según los espacios, y que en el caso de que no hayan las suficientes celdas, se puedan generar más para que el texto pueda caber.

Comment: Lo que pides es un poco raro.
desde luego no se puede hacer solo con html.
yo empezaría poniendo un input o un text dentro de cada td (al principio solo uno)
y luego recorrería el texto buscando espacios y saltos de línea y a partir del resultado construiría la tabla.

Comment: Otra forma de hacerlo seria poniendo un input y un botón, el cual activara el codigo javascript necesario para realizar eso que pides. El problema es que no has puesto nada de eso en la pregunta ni el error que te esté dando, y **aqui no hacemos código a medida**, lo siento. Si tan solo quieres opiniones, tampoco podemos dártelas en una respuesta, pues no se aceptan preguntas así, pues este sitio **no es un foro** tampoco. Lee [ask] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento **básico** de este sitio, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberás ocupar el API del [clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard) y el evento onpaste

Luego un split("\n") para separar por filas y un split(" ") para separar por espacios y listo

Texto para probar:

```
Este es un texto
de prueba
```

```js
const TABLA = document.getElementById("Tabla");
let FilasCant = 1;
let ColsCant = 3;


function Pegar(row, col) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let texto = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    let lineas = texto.split("\n");
    
    for (let l = 0; l < lineas.length; l++) {
        if (lineas[l].length == 0) continue;
        let celdas = lineas[l].split(" ");
        // let lineas = texto.split("\t"); //para pegar desde excel 
       
        if (l + row > FilasCant) {
            CrearFila();
        }

        for (let c = 0; c < celdas.length;c++) {
            if (c + col > ColsCant) {
                CrearColumna();
            }
            GetCelda(l + row, c + col).innerHTML = celdas[c];
        }

                
    }
}

function GetCelda(row, col) {
    return TABLA.querySelector("tr[data-row='" + row + "']").querySelectorAll("td")[col - 1];
}

function presskey(row,col){
    if (event.keyCode === 13){ 
        event.preventDefault();

        if (row === FilasCant) {
            CrearFila();
            GetCelda(FilasCant, col).focus();
        }
        else {
            GetCelda(row+1, col).focus();
        }
    }
}

function CrearColumna() {
    let filas = TABLA.querySelectorAll("tr");
    ColsCant++;
    filas.forEach((fila,i) => {
        fila.append(CrearCelda(i + 1, ColsCant));
    });
            
}

function CrearCelda(row,col) {
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.contentEditable=true;
    td.setAttribute("onkeypress", "presskey(" + row + "," + col + ")");
    td.setAttribute("onpaste", "Pegar(" + row + "," + col + ")");
    return td;
}

function CrearFila() {
    FilasCant++;
    let tr =  document.createElement("tr");
    tr.setAttribute("data-row", FilasCant);

    for(let i = 1; i <= ColsCant; i++){
        tr.appendChild(CrearCelda(FilasCant,i));
    }
            
    TABLA.appendChild(tr);
          
}
```

```css
td
{
  width:120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
    <tbody id="Tabla">
        <tr data-row="1">
            <td contenteditable="true" onkeypress="presskey(1,1)" onpaste="Pegar(1,1)" ></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" onkeypress="presskey(1,2)" onpaste="Pegar(1,2)" ></td>
            <td contenteditable="true" onkeypress="presskey(1,3)" onpaste="Pegar(1,3)" ></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```